# Does anyone have access to bheedaa panchanga from 'Dashavidyaa Rahasya' of Rudrayaamala Tantra

Tags: worship, tantra, devi, manuscripts

Three panchaangas of the 'Dasha vidyaa' part form of the parishishtha of Devi Rahasya by Ramchandra Kak and Harbhatta Shastrii.
Those are
1) Jvaalaamukhi
2) Shaarikaa
3) Mahaarajni
In other material available in printed form
4) [Pratyangiraa Panchaanga](https://archive.org/details/PratyangiraPanchangaVenkateshwarPress_201807) (Khemraj Press )
A few in manuscript form:
5) Indraakshi
6) Sarasvati
7) Kaali ( Only Patala and Paddhati )
8) Bhuvaneshvari
9) Tripurasundari
(These are different from the regular panchaangas of Dasha Maha Vidyaa)
The tenth name has to be 'Bhiidaa' as explained in Dakshinamurti's Uddhaar Kosha, but nothing is available except the mantra and the dhyaana of Bhiidaa / BheeDaa.

Panchaanga means
1) Patala (The mantra and Yantra)
2) Paddhati ( Pooja paddhati)
3) Kavacham
4) Sahasranaamam
5) Stotram ( Mostly Mantragarbham)

The Mundamaalaa Tantra depicts Dasha 'Maha' Vidyaa as follows
1) Kaali
2) Taaraa
3) Shodashi (Tripurasundari)
4) Bhuvaneshvarii
5) Chhinnamastaa
6) Tripurabhairavii
7) Dhoomaavatii
8) Bagalaamukhii
9) Maatangii
10) Kamalaatmikaa (Lakshmii)

[Mantra Mahaarnava](https://archive.org/details/Mantra_Maharnava_Khemraj_Edition) and [Shaakta Pramod](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.541555) contain all the above 10 panchangas.

Uddhaara Kosha of Dakshinaamoortii included as a parishishtha of [Devi Rahasya](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.313570) names the Dasha Vidyaa (not Dasha Maha Vidyaa) as
1) Tripuraa (Tripura Sundari)
2) Shree (Lakshmii)
3) Vaagdevii (Sarasvatii)
4) Taaraa
5) Bhuvaneshvarii
6) Matangii
7) Shaarikaa
8) Rajnii
9) Bhiidaa
10) Jvaalaamukhii

The Dasha Vidyaa Rahasya of the Rudrayaalamala Tantra is not available fully at one place. Taaraa, Maatangii, Lakshmii and Bheedaa panchangas are missing from the 'Dasha Vidyaa Rahasya' and Pratyangiraa, Indrakshii and Kaalii are additional entries.

Comment: the question is not clear... panchangam can be for any deity... 5 things for pooja. secondly why are you mixing multiple references . use a single text like sharda tikala or mantra mahodadhi for list of maha vidyas

Comment: Shaaradaa Tilak and Mantra Mahodadhii are rather basic texts containing basic knowledge about mantra dhyaana etc. There is not a single panchaanga in both these texts. I am talking about advanced detailed knowledge about specific deities.

Comment: no its not clear if you are looking for their names or their panchangam or wat ?  or you are looking for dhyana.... the most accepted list of mahavidya is kali , tara.. and so on.

Comment: I am looking for the missing panchaanga of Bheedaa from Dasha vidyaa rahasya.

Comment: Then please form question accordingly.  Current question is more like names of mahavidyas